# Why are my widgets not saving when being added to a sidebar?

Tags: themes, widgets, sidebar

The following is in my `function.php` file. I see the sidebar in my `Appearance > Widgets` page but whenever I drag something on over the sidebar and save it just disappears once I leave the admin area.

I've scoured the web and the only solution I seem to find is that I need to disable ALL plugin to find the culprit... which I've done to no avail.

If I switch the theme to the WP 2012 theme then it seems to work, only my theme seems to break it.

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'ditto_register_sidebars' );

function ditto_register_sidebars() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => __( 'Right Hand Sidebar' ),
        'id' => 'rightBar',
        'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on the right-hand side.' )
    ));
}
```

This is my `sidebar-rightBar.php` file:

```
<?php
if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('rightBar') ) :
endif; ?>
```

and how I include it in my theme:

```
<?php get_sidebar( 'rightBar' ); ?>
```

Just a quick note, I'm running on version 3.5.2.

I've tried to save in both Chrome and Firefox and my javascript console isn't giving me any problems. I've also tried to do it in accessibility mode with no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its the camel-case in the widget ID. The following works:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'ditto_register_sidebars' );

function ditto_register_sidebars() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => __( 'Right Hand Sidebar' ),
        'id' => 'right-bar',
        'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on the right-hand side.' )
    ));
}
```

Per the Codex:

> id - Sidebar id - Must be all in lowercase, with no spaces (default is
>   a numeric auto-incremented ID).
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Comment: There's Stackexchange for you. Old answers with great solutions! Just saved me some time, thanks.

Comment: I keep coming back on this page, made this mistake again :)